# Rescaling a grid into mobile screen in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

I have a 32 by 64 grid and I am trying to display that on the mobile screen with a noble amount of margin along the edge.

Consider 2 by 2 grid for an example. Then we have 4 total nodes here.

Inside each node, I have x position, y position, and random value at the end. So this 2 by 2 grid will be represented as below.

```
[[0,0,376],[1,0,836],[0,1,888],[1,1,123]]
```

Like this example, my 32 by 64 grid will have the same structure as above.

Now when I draw this information on the screen, the information above is directly translated into a pixel position.

So in my android emulator, it is literally starting from the top-left place and then ends up drawing a really small grid.

Now I want to scale this information onto the screen's size with margins.

I have trouble creating a function that creates a new array that holds corrected x and y values that fits the screen of the phone. The third value (random number) should be kept untouched.

The function (in my idea) should take the 3 following inputs:

- My current array (32 by 64 with the format above)
- Margin of choice (ex. 50 if the margin of 50 pixels is wanted)
- Width and height of the phone (screen size so that depending on that, new array is generated containing pixel position of that node)

I hope this picture can clarify the situation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you given this any look?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Auto-arranging is part of the design of these grids in CSS/HTML. Might be what you're looking for, or possibly not. This setup is very popular in WebRTC developments containing conference calls and has been done two ways, with Grids, or via JavaScript to re-size everything on Window.Resize event.